# Cannot connect to tomcat externally

Tags: linux, tomcat, opensuse

[image]

I install the tomcat server on my openSuse port 8080, but I can connect to http://127.0.0.1:8080 only in my local machine.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Are you trying to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` from a *different* machine? That won't work, because 127.0.0.1 resolves to the local machine (i.e. `localhost`). Or is it not working on the local machine itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you have a linux firewall like iptables configured?

If it's iptables you can fix this with this statement

```
  iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

(You change your iptables config to accept external tcp connections, please make shure that you know what you are doing if your are editing firewall ports)